# Callback function timeout/disruption in google Pub/Sub asynchronous pull subscriber

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a subscriber application which pulls from a Google Cloud Pub/Sub asynchronously using the google-cloud-pubsub python library.

I am running into intermittent issues where my callback function doesnt finish running/is interrupted. Unfortunately I dont have any errors, I only know this is the case because it does not finish writing data to an external source.

for example, in the following sample code:

```
subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()
subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path(
    project, subscription_name)

def callback(message):
    print('Received message: {}'.format(message))
    message.ack()

# Limit the subscriber to only have ten outstanding messages at a time.
flow_control = pubsub_v1.types.FlowControl(max_messages=10)
subscriber.subscribe(
    subscription_path, callback=callback, flow_control=flow_control)

# The subscriber is non-blocking, so we must keep the main thread from
# exiting to allow it to process messages in the background.
print('Listening for messages on {}'.format(subscription_path))
while True:
    time.sleep(60)
```

the code in the callback function may sometimes take a while, and in some cases, I have noticed that it does not finish executing/seems to be disrupted by something.

Could that ever happen? is there a timeout on this function?

Comment: Can you try changing time.sleep() value? 
Do you observe a different behavior?

Comment: I'm having similar problem with my `golang` routine. My callback function does take long - line ~2 min. Did you find any solution @J.LValtueña and @Soroosh Avazkhani